# View and Dowload Files from Directory

Tags: php

I currently have a script which allows users to view files within a directory.  I am wondering how I can make these files downloadable as well. I think it has something to do with the index.php but not sure.  Thought I best just check and clarify My script is below.

```
        <?php

$path = "/home/phpprac/assesment"; 


$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path"); 


while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) { 

if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "index.php" ) 

    continue; 
    echo "<a href=\"$file\">$file</a><br />"; 

} 
// Close 
closedir($dir_handle);
```

?>

Comment: Shouldn't your files be downloadable already?

Comment: Unfortunately they are not. Not entirely sure why

Answer (score 0):

You need to know full path to file.

So, if you have server root path **/home/phpprac/**, your path is **/assesment** and you need write link:

```
echo "<a href=\"/assesment{$file}\">$file</a><br />";
```

Other posibility is you link to text files and browser ust open instead download. You can fix by making php script, whitch opens a file and send it with header **'Content-Type: application/force-download'**

```
<?
$file_name = $_GET['file'];
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
readfile($file_name);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your files should be downloadable . You can filter your extension like below istead using ugly `continue` statement

```
 foreach (glob('*.{jpg,gif,zip,doc}', GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
        echo "<a href=".$filename." target='_blank'>".$filename."</a><br/>";
    }
```